# Can't extend the Sound object prototype

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object, audio, prototype

I'm new to programming. I need to add new properties to the Sound object, but I can't get it to work. This is what I'm doing:

```
S31 = new Sound();
S31.load(new URLRequest("mp3/S31.mp3"));
Sound.prototype.correctas = 0;
trace(S31.correctas);
```

I get this error message:

"1119: Access of possibly undefined property correctas through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound".

I don't know what to do.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype class really isn't used in as3 (please someone correct me if I'm wrong here, I know its include but I'm not really sure why you would use it.)

You can create [dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514479/how-to-create-a-as3-dynamic-class-and-how-to-use-it) classes that allow you to add properties to them at runtime but in this case I would stick to OOP.

What you would want to do is create a class that extends Sound and holds whatever extended functionality you want to include. This new class will [inherit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29) all the functionality of the base Sound class.

Try [creating a new AS3 class](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/creating_class_as3.html) and having it extend Sound

```
package src {
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundLoaderContext;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class MySound extends Sound{

    public var correctas:Number; //assuming you are using a Number here          

    //sound takes two params in its constructor 
    public function MySound(stream:URLRequest=null, context:SoundLoaderContext=null){
    //super passes these params to the super class
        super(stream, context);
     }
}
```

Now to use this you would create a new MySound object instead of Sound

```
 var s31:MySound = new MySound();
 s31.load(new URLRequest("mp3/S31.mp3"));
 s31.correctas = 0;
 trace(s31.correctas) //will be 0
```